# Deploying Angular Application doesn't seem to do anything on my server

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote a small Angular application.

I would like to publish this for others to access. It's nothing more than just the app.component.

But I used the `ng build --prod`

took my dist folder called My-App and uploaded it to a work test server we usually use for wordpress sites.

http://azipit.co.za/TestingAngular/My-App/

But as you can see nothing happens.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,800;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-test></app-test>
<script src="runtime.e227d1a0e31cbccbf8ec.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.a4021de53358bb0fec14.js" defer></script><script src="main.72a2219f9423e8d76207.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

[image]

The Tutorials are confusing me a little. Am I doing something wrong?

Note:

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.4
Node: 12.14.1
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.0.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.4
@angular/cli                      10.0.4
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.4
@schematics/angular               10.0.4
@schematics/update                0.1000.4
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

trying:

```
ng build -d /TestingAngular/My-App/ --prod 

//Results in:

Unknown option: '-d'
Unknown option: '/TestingAngular/My-App/'
```

Comment: can you describe your deployment steps in more detail?

Comment: well I just used ng build --prod Went to my Dist folder zipped it uploaded to my server unzipped and thats it

Comment: Site is not working anymore :(

Comment: Please check updated version

Comment: Uploaded again have a look errors come out weird 
```http://azipit.co.za/TestingAngular/My-App/TestingAngular/runtime.e227d1a0e31cbccbf8ec.js
```

Comment: My fault, excuse me, please.  It should start from the slash :  ```--baseHref=/TestingAngular/My-App```

Comment: Sorry ive lost you a little now so ```npm run build --baseHref=TestingAngular/My-App --prod ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218518/discussion-between-drag13-and-someguy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you serving site, not from the root.
You need to specify the correct path on build:

```
npm run build -- --prod --baseHref=/TestingAngular/My-App
```

If you check the console, you will see 404 errors for not found assets.

Comment: So instead of saying ng build --prod i need to say ng build -d /TestingAngular/My-App/ --prod? or w.e my root path is This is the Response

```ng build -d /TestingAngular/My-App/ --prod
Unknown option: '-d'
Unknown option: '/TestingAngular/My-App/'
```

Comment: Yep, it trying to get scripts from ```<script src="runtime.e227d1a0e31cbccbf8ec.js" ````

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: Updating qeustion Under Note: for Version

Comment: Don't worry, your posts are not offensive. Please note that Stack Overflow is a collaborative effort. We all care for the information we post here. This is not a personal support desk, and we all edit posts to make them better. I can't stop editing posts and I can't pay special attention to your account. If you are not happy with me editing HTH out of your posts then either stop adding it or raise this issue on [meta].

Comment: @Dharman Yes, I am not happy with your changes and I gladly raise this question in Meta. Until I don't see direct forbids, I am pretty sure it is ok to be polite in a manner I want.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is nothing to do with servers either you are deploying to Windows or Linux.

**Step1:** build the angular application

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing none --build-optimizer true
```

**Step2:** Deploy on Server

**Step3:** Setup your domain to pick by default Index.htm file

Now, ready to go.